# How do I use the LIKE query in and UPDATE statement? *Example provided*

Tags: sql, ms-access

I just started learning SQL so I'm not that adept at it yet and I wasn't really sure how to do my research on this one because I couldn't word the question properly so I decided to ask a question for myself.

Alright, so here's what I'm trying to do in my particular case:
**I use Microsoft Access 2010.** In my table called "MEMBERS" I have a field called "Address". The entries in this column are really messy so I'm trying to tidy it up. Some of the entries contain 'Road' while others contain 'Rd'. What I want to do is update the columns that have 'Road' in them and change that word only to 'Rd' without affecting the rest of the address.

*So if one of the entries were '7 Example Road' I would like to create a query to change it to '7 Example Rd'.*

This is the query I tried to use:

```
UPDATE MEMBERS
SET 'Rd'
WHERE Address LIKE '*Road'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE Address Like '%Road'` here.  Also which column are you setting to 'Rd'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `REPLACE()` function.

```
UPDATE MEMBERS
SET Address = REPLACE(Address, 'Road', 'Rd')
WHERE Address LIKE '*Road'
```

Comment: That `REPLACE()` call would replace *all* occurrences of the sequence `Road` in the address, no matter where it's positioned in the string (of course, *one* of the occurrences must be at the end to satisfy the `WHERE` clause). This could be troubling if its actually part of a longer name.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!!

Is there any way to give you the best answer or anything? I'm new to this forum.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for too. You rock!